# odd appearance of colors with viridis in PDFs viewed by Preview v. Adobe

Tags: r, macos, pdf

I've been creating heatmaps using `heatmap.2()` in R.

I'm using the `viridis()` color scale.

I used `pdf()` to create the output.

As you can see the color key looks different when viewing the PDF file using Adobe Acrobat (top panel) v. using Preview (bottom panel) in OS X (version 11.3.1).  The Adobe Acrobat appearance is closer to what I expect.  The colors in Preview appear washed out and undersaturated.

Has anyone else had this experience?

[image: comparison of color in Adobe Acrobat v. Preview]

*Code added after original post:*

The following code generates the "washed out" color key in the heatmap:

```
library ('viridis')
library('gplots')
test.matrix <- matrix(ncol=25, nrow=9, -4:4)
breaks <- seq(-4,4,0.5)
pdf(file='heatmap.pdf', width=10, height=6)
heatmap.2(test.matrix, density.info = 'none',  trace='none', 
  Colv = F, Rowv = F, dendrogram = 'none', 
  col=viridis(length(breaks)-1), breaks=breaks 
          )
dev.off()
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be related to color profiles, but I don't know how to control from R output: https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/urgent-colors-washed-out-after-exporting-to-pdf/m-p/11327363

Comment: "Has anyone else had this experience?" is the only actual question I find in your posting. Is that all you want to know for the bounty? Or are you looking for an explanation or even a work-around?

Comment: I'm looking for more an explanation and then a work around to have Preview render the PDF closer to what I expect.  Currently the work around is to use Adobe Acrobat rather than Preview.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Reader (default settings) does not display plots exactly as they are stored in the file. You can play around with the settings at Edit > Preferences > Page Display. Try to open the file with another PDF reader and you probably see a difference. The Adobe program also makes thin lines appear thicker, smoothes low resolution images, fills gaps between nearby lines etc.

Comment: Actually, Adobe Reader is truer to what I expect than Preview.

Answer (score 0):

Visual comment - not an answer for bounty.

As per [Jon-Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680197/odd-appearance-of-colors-with-viridis-in-pdfs-viewed-by-preview-v-adobe#comment119774085_67680197) comment above.

It is not a difference per app as such, here is the exact same input file with colour profiles toggled on and off on the same screen. Note my simulation unlike the OP affects the Pixelated Text. I am using an RGB image from 1st example above rather than Coloured Objects However it shows the underlying difference.

[image]
[image]

I would thus suggest looking for any colour profile related settings in `Preview`

Comment: I tried assigning a color profile in Preview, but apparently that option is greyed out.  I think you have that option if you're e.g. viewing a JPG but not a PDF.